# Keep getting ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4474, 10), indices imply (14084, 10)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

First off, thanks in advance if you can help puzzle this out! I'm trying to balance some customer data for my model. My targets are all 1s and 0s, and the 0s are overwhelmingly abundant. So I created a counter that will start to delete the 0 rows once they surpass the number of 1 rows. But at the very end of my code, when I create the np.delete to get those extra rows off my dataset I keep getting this error

I don't really know what to try, because I don't even understand what the error is telling me

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn import preprocessing
#%%
#Loading the Raw Data
raw_csv_data= pd.read_csv('Audiobooks-data_raw.csv')
print(display(raw_csv_data.head(20)))
#%%
df=raw_csv_data.copy()
print(display(df.head(20)))
#%%
print(df.info())
#%%
#Separate the Targets from the dataset
inputs_all= df.loc[:,'Book length (mins)_overall':'Last visited minus Purchase date']
targets_all= df['Targets']
print(display(inputs_all.head()))
print(display(targets_all.head()))
#%%
#Shuffling the Data to prep for balancing
shuffled_indices= np.arange(inputs_all.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(shuffled_indices)
shuffled_inputs= inputs_all.iloc[shuffled_indices]
shuffled_targets= targets_all[shuffled_indices]
#%%
#Balance the Dataset
#There are significantly more 0's than 1's in our target.
#We want a good accurate model
print(inputs_all.shape)
print(targets_all.shape)
#%%
num_one_targets= int(np.sum(targets_all))
zero_targets_counter= 0
indices_to_remove= []
print(num_one_targets)
#%%
for i in range(targets_all.shape[0]):
    if targets_all[i]==0:
        zero_targets_counter +=1
        if zero_targets_counter> num_one_targets:
            indices_to_remove.append(i)

#%%

inputs_all_balanced= np.delete(inputs_all, indices_to_remove, axis=0)
targets_all_balanced= np.delete(targets_all, indices_to_remove, axis=0)
```

Everything works except when I try to group my balanced datasets and delete the excess 0 rows. Here is the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1652 
-> 1653         mgr = BlockManager(blocks, axes)
   1654         mgr._consolidate_inplace()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in __init__(self, blocks, axes, do_integrity_check)
    113         if do_integrity_check:
--> 114             self._verify_integrity()
    115 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in _verify_integrity(self)
    310             if block._verify_integrity and block.shape[1:] != mgr_shape[1:]:
--> 311                 construction_error(tot_items, block.shape[1:], self.axes)
    312         if len(self.items) != tot_items:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   1690     raise ValueError("Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(
-> 1691         passed, implied))
   1692 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4474, 10), indices imply (14084, 10)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 inputs_all_balanced= np.delete(inputs_all, indices_to_remove, axis=0)
      2 targets_all_balanced= np.delete(targets_all, indices_to_remove, axis=0)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in delete(arr, obj, axis)
   4419 
   4420     if wrap:
-> 4421         return wrap(new)
   4422     else:
   4423         return new

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __array_wrap__(self, result, context)
   1907     def __array_wrap__(self, result, context=None):
   1908         d = self._construct_axes_dict(self._AXIS_ORDERS, copy=False)
-> 1909         return self._constructor(result, **d).__finalize__(self)
   1910 
   1911     # ideally we would define this to avoid the getattr checks, but

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    422             else:
    423                 mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype,
--> 424                                    copy=copy)
    425 
    426         # For data is list-like, or Iterable (will consume into list)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in init_ndarray(values, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    165         values = maybe_infer_to_datetimelike(values)
    166 
--> 167     return create_block_manager_from_blocks([values], [columns, index])
    168 
    169 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1658         blocks = [getattr(b, 'values', b) for b in blocks]
   1659         tot_items = sum(b.shape[0] for b in blocks)
-> 1660         construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
   1661 
   1662 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   1689         raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")
   1690     raise ValueError("Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(
-> 1691         passed, implied))
   1692 
   1693 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4474, 10), indices imply (14084, 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing rows with pandas drop instead:

```
inputs_all_balanced  = inputs_all.drop(indices_to_remove,axis=0)
targets_all_balanced = targets_all.drop(indices_to_remove,axis=0)
```

Comment: Wow! @Moe. that worked. Thank you! could you tell me why it was throwing that error? And how you figured out to do that? I'm thinking it might have something to do with numpy vs pandas but I don't get it.

Comment: Your variables inputs_all, targets_all are both dataframes from pandas. Trying to delete rows of pandas dataframe with numpy is a bit risky which might break things. Since pandas has standard method of drop for doing so,  you don't want to mix the two since there is different between numpy array and pnadas dataframe structure.